# Is there a way to turn this hulk of code into an R function?

Tags: r, function

I'm not extremely adept with R and recently I've been trying to learn how to write functions well. So I have a section of code that if I write out in a "non-function" way, it will end up being over a thousand lines of code. The problem is that it's really only about six lines of "unique" code but its running on different subsets of a large data set.

```
df <- subset(data, FileName == "File Name" & Category == "Category Name" & Case == "Case Name")
df <- df %>% group_by(TestNum) %>% summarise(FileName = FileName[1], Version = Version[1], Measure = Measure[1], RepMean = mean(Value), Case = Case[1])
df <- df[c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6)]
df$Sigma1 <- (df$RepMean > (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) + sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))|(df$RepMean < (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) - sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))
df$Sigma2 <- (df$RepMean > (mean(df$RepMean,na.rm=TRUE)) + 2 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))) | (df$RepMean < (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) - 2 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)))
df$Sigma3 <- (df$RepMean > (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) + 3 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))) | (df$RepMean < (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) - 3 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

The original data set has 6 unique values in the `FileName` column, 7 in the `Category` column, and 4 in the `Case` column which means that I'm creating 168 unique `df` data frames with these lines of code that I'm using `rbind.fill` on to create a single data frame ("StatTable") that I then run this on:

```
LatestTestNum <- max(data$TestNum, na.rm=TRUE)
ControlTable <- subset(StatTable, (Sigma1 == "TRUE" | Sigma2 == "TRUE" | Sigma3 == "TRUE") & TestNum == LatestTestNum)
ControlTable <- ControlTable[, c("FileName, "Category", "Case", "Sigma1", "Sigma2", "Sigma3")]
```

Where `ControlTable` is the end product I'm looking for.

So is this something where a function would greatly reduce my tedious pain? Especially when I want to modify the way this works, it requires changing every single df code by hand.

**EDIT:** Here's an explanation of what is found in each column of the original data set.

```
Column1:FileName -- The name of the file that the data comes from
Column2:Version -- The version of the software that data comes from
Column3:Category -- The particular data type measured
Column4:Value -- The value of the data
Column5:TestNum -- TestNum is an integer value associated with the version number. This makes it easier to organize and sort data rather than using the Version column which is a string. (So for example version 1.0 might be TestNum=1 and 1.1 TestNum=2)
Column6:RepNum -- The replication count of that version. (Files are run multiple times per version)
Column7:Case -- There are different ways that the software is "setup" for data collection.
```

**Here's a working data set.**

```
FileName <- c("File1","File1","File1","File1","File2","File2","File2","File2","File1","File1","File1","File1","File2","File2","File2","File2","File1","File1","File1","File1","File2","File2","File2","File2","File1","File1","File1","File1","File2","File2","File2","File2")
Version <- c("1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2","1.0.2")
Category <- c("Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2")
Value <- rpois(n = 32, lambda = 100)
TestNum <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
RepNum <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Case <- c("Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case1","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2","Case2")
df <- data.frame(FileName,Version,Category,Value,TestNum,RepNum,Case)
```

**2nd EDIT:** I've provided an answer myself because I've worked out a function that will do the basic steps that lead to the various "df"'s with unique "FileName", "Category", and "Case". I still would like to be able to fold in the need to rbind 168 different data frames but the primary thing I'd also like to be able to add into this function is the ability to filter out certain `TestNum`'s easily.

So for example, one of my unique data frames works best with this subset:

```
df <- subset(data, FileName == "File1" & Category == "Category1" & Case == "Case1" &
TestNum > 11)
```

but another data frame might work best with this subset:

```
df <- subset(data, FileName == "File1" & Category == "Category1" & Case == "Case1" &
(TestNum > 8 & TestNum != 21 & TestNum != 32))
```

I figure I should be able to add "TestNum" as another argument to my function but I'm not sure how I could allow for this much control on how much I can filter.

### Fun extra challenge:

Because I'm working with a large existing data set, I've tweaked each sigma value so that certain data points are filtered out of the mean and standard deviation calculations (this is necessary to actually be any use in detecting new data points that fall outside of these sigma values -- the entire purpose of this code). Is there a way to write a function that also allows for this same tweaking?

Comment: At the top: `myFunction <- function(data, FileNameStr, CategoryStr, CaseStr) {` second line becomes `df<-subset(data,FileName == FileNameStr & Category == CategoryStr & Case == CaseStr)` and at the end, add `return(df)` followed by `}` on a separate line. This should be pretty close.

Comment: The usual strategy is to figure out what is being repeated and avoid that repetition in a function.

Comment: @lmo So if I understand correctly, if I wrote a function, `myFunction` that just had what you listed, it should essentially mirror the subset function, correct?

Comment: That's right, you add your additional code with `df$Sigma1<-` and so so on above `return(df)`. Also, consider using spacing for better readability.

Comment: @lmo Thanks, I actually had something mixed up which prompted my comment. Nothing was being subset which seemed.. odd haha. But I have it figured out.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do without seeing any data ... can you provided some using `dput(df)` where df is a portion of your dataframe? It is also unclear whether `TestNum` is unique and/or related to other variables.

Comment: @ssp3nc3r I'll add a detailed explanation of what each column is. I won't provide an example of data because if I provided data, it would require a minimum of 64 rows to give a sense of how the data works.

Comment: @ssp3nc3r Oh and I can't provide a portion of the data using `dput(df)` because the data is on an isolated machine.

Comment: If you can't supply the specific data, perhaps you can re write your question using a dataset that we all have, then, such as `diamonds` (which, like your data, includes both categorical and numeric variables) in the package `ggplot2`? Without providing data you are asking a lot from people.

Comment: @ssp3nc3r See my most recent edit.

Comment: Your comment at the end of the question about the "main purpose of the code" is a red flag that you may have the XY problem. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378. If so, a new question is probably in order rather than reworking this one, but if you do that, do refer to this one for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 168 unique FileName/Category/Case combinations, it would seem entirely natural to use `dplyr` the way you do within your function. First group by FileName/Category/Case/TestNum and get your RepMeans, then group by FileName/Category/Case and do the calculations to get if it is 1, 2, or 3 SD's away. Rather than your comparison code, here I compute the number of SDs away first and then use that, which feels more natural and also repeats the computations less.

```
df %>% group_by(FileName, Category, Case, TestNum) %>%
       summarise(RepMean = mean(Value)) %>%
       group_by(FileName, Category, Case) %>%
       mutate(diff.sd = abs((RepMean - mean(RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))/sd(RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)),
              Sigma1 = diff.sd > 1,
              Sigma2 = diff.sd > 2,
              Sigma3 = diff.sd > 3)
```

For your additional subsetting, that seems most natural to me to think of it as simply removing the rows you don't want, rather than including the one you do. Once you've removed them from the full data set, you can just run this code.

EDIT to demonstrate output: Here I show output with sigma values of 1+, 2+, and 3+, by adding outliers to your original data, and also adapting it to have more data points in each group and only one in each TestNum. In this version, I also output the group mean, sd, and size to be sure it's all working correctly.

```
df$Case <- "Case1"
df$Category <- "Category1"
df$TestNum <- 1:nrow(df)
df$Value[1] <- 5000
df$Value[5] <- 140
out <- df %>% group_by(FileName, Category, Case, TestNum) %>%
       summarise(RepMean = mean(Value)) %>%
       group_by(FileName, Category, Case) %>%
           mutate(group.mean=mean(RepMean, na.rm=TRUE),
                  group.sd=sd(RepMean, na.rm=TRUE),
                  group.n=length(RepMean),
                  diff.sd = abs((RepMean - mean(RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))/sd(RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)),
              Sigma1 = diff.sd > 1,
              Sigma2 = diff.sd > 2,
              Sigma3 = diff.sd > 3)
head(out[order(-out$diff.sd),])
## Source: local data frame [6 x 12]
## Groups: FileName, Category, Case [2]
##  
##   FileName  Category  Case TestNum RepMean group.mean   group.sd group.n   diff.sd Sigma1 Sigma2 Sigma3
##     <fctr>     <chr> <chr>   <int>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>   <int>     <dbl>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
## 1    File1 Category1 Case1       1    5000   402.4375 1226.06857      16 3.7498413   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
## 2    File2 Category1 Case1       5     140   103.5625   13.29646      16 2.7403912   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
## 3    File2 Category1 Case1      13      85   103.5625   13.29646      16 1.3960483   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
## 4    File2 Category1 Case1      15     118   103.5625   13.29646      16 1.0858154   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
## 5    File2 Category1 Case1      16      90   103.5625   13.29646      16 1.0200084   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
## 6    File2 Category1 Case1      14      91   103.5625   13.29646      16 0.9448004  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: I haven't been able to track down why but the resulting df from your code is giving me different booleans in my sigma columns than my other code. Wouldn't the Sigma1-3 values need to be checked for values +/- `diff.sd`?

Comment: Yes, that would be it, I forgot the `abs`. Will edit.

Comment: Something is still awry. An example, row1 RepMean = 1918.000, diff.sd = 1.3073825 but df has Sigma1,2,3 all showing "TRUE".

Comment: So for that particular row, the stdev value is 13.50829. The mean is 1352.49 which means that the RepMean value of 1918 lies well outside of the Sigma3 range. However, your example code makes it look like `Sigma1 = True` when `diff.sd > 1` / `Sigma2 = True` when `diff.sd > 2` / `Sigma3 = True` when `diff.sd > 3`. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: See edit which demonstrates output on reproducible data.

Comment: How did you get TestNum's like that? There should only be 1 and 2 values.

Comment: See my code. I don't think it matters, does it? I needed more data to be able to get more possible values for diff/sd so I could have all the possible values of sigma1, sigma2, and sigma3.

Comment: But wait a minute!! If there are only two TestNum values, then for each combination of FileNum/Category/Case, won't there by only two values? If so, the abs(diff/sd) will always be the same and this won't do anything interesting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that I've worked out:

```
myFunction <- function(df,FileNameStr,CategoryStr,CaseStr){
    df <- subset(df, FileName == FileNameStr & Category == CategoryStr & Case == CaseStr)
    df <- df %>% group_by(TestNum) %>% summarise(FileName = FileName[1], Version = Version[1], Category = Category[1], RepMean = mean(Value), Case = Case[1])
    df <- df[c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6)]
    df$Sigma1 <- (df$RepMean > (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) + sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))|(df$RepMean < (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) - sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))
    df$Sigma2 <- (df$RepMean > (mean(df$RepMean,na.rm=TRUE)) + 2 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))) | (df$RepMean < (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) - 2 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)))
    df$Sigma3 <- (df$RepMean > (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) + 3 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE))) | (df$RepMean < (mean(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)) - 3 * (sd(df$RepMean, na.rm=TRUE)))
    return(df)
}
```

Optimally, I'd love to somehow work in the `rbind.fill` bit into this. I feel like there must be a quicker way to do that than manually type out 168 data frame names into the function. Nonetheless, this is the function for creating each of those data frames.

**EDIT:** I've made an edit (under "2nd EDIT") to my original question that explains more about my need to be able to add filtering capabilities to this function.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, I fixed the typo